# Using Three.js as Closure library?

Tags: three.js, google-closure-compiler

Looking at Three.js's build script, I see they use Google Closure compiler. I am having a small script utilizing Three.js. Can I use Google Closure to compile the script with Three.js as a library (instead of having Three.min.js preambled or included in an HTML  tag) so the final output javascript is much smaller.

I'm asking this because I don't see any `goog.provide` in Three.js source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the build command does not specify a compilation level. That means it is using the default `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

If that is indeed true, then no, you probably cannot include the source as a library as it is not compatible with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

Comment: well I want to know how can I change it so that I can include the sourc as a library

Comment: Converting a large code base to be compatible with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` can be daunting. See http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html?m=1 for some of the biggest issues.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to prepend the three.js script to the compiler output using whatever shell or build system you are using.