# Why isn't Closure Compiler trimming down Three.js completely?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am copying the source of THREE.js from [this link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.js), and pasting it into Closure Compiler UI. I have the following options set:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @language ECMASCRIPT5
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

Yet, for some reason, clicking compile only gets this down to 271KB uncompressed.

My question is, THREE.js doesn't seem to have any exports, so why doesn't Closure Compiler trim it out completely with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`?

I am building a library on top of THREE.js, and would like to utilize Closure Compiler's dead code removal to make the bundle more manageable. What else should I be doing to trim out functions in THREE.js that are never called?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that three.js is [compatible with Closure-compiler's ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933100/1211524).

The over 1800 warnings I got when compiling the source were a pretty big clue as well.